# Global variable declaration of structure in C

Tags: c, global-variables, structure

Can you give me the meaning of this code in C language?

This is the global variable definition.

```
 static const struct_name global_variable_name = // (Added equals to here)
 {
   function_call_1, // (comma instead of semicolon)
   function_call_2, // ditto
   NULL,
   NULL,
 }
```

Comment: What you show is not valid C unless you have a preprocessor `#define global_variable_name function_name(optional_args)` to make it into a function definition, and then the body of the function is mostly pointless unless the `function_call_1;` is really written with parentheses to make it a function call (or there's another macro to resolve that problem), and ditto for `function_call_2;`, and the two `NULL;` statements are pointless.  If you had commas instead of semicolons, another set of hackery could make it compilable.  But it isn't meaningful as written.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If almost looks like something trying to initialise a struct (but the equals is missing and the semicolons should be commas). Where does this code come from and does it compile in its environment?

Given a struct (I am guessing about what kind of struct it is):

```
struct struct_name
{
    void* func1;
    void* func2;
    void* something1;
    void* something2;
};
```

And some function pointers:

```
void* func1 = NULL;
void* func2 = NULL;
```

Then your code with = to initialize and commas for the args:

```
static const  struct_name  global_variable_name = 
{
   func1,
   func2,
   NULL,
   NULL,
};
```

Just a guess, as the code that you provided does not compile and is not valid. It looks like it might be some #define trickery, are either `struct_name` or `global_variable_name` #defines?

**Update**

Based on your latest edit and your comment:

> yes you are right, I modified the code. This is the global variable definition.

Then, what is happening is that the code is initialising a global variable `global_variable_name` of type `struct_name` which is a struct. In the same way that you can initialize an integer when you declare it as follows:

```
int myInteger = 1;
```

You can initialize a struct when you declare it. Let's take a simpler case:

```
struct simple_struct
{
    int val1;
    int val2;
};

static const  simple_struct  global_simpleStruct = 
 {
   1,
   2
 };

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "val1:" << global_simpleStruct.val1 << ", val2:" << global_simpleStruct.val2;
    return 0;
}
```

The output will be: `val1:1, val2:2`

See the information **[here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_%28C_programming_language%29)** and search for 'struct initialization'.

Hopefully this makes it clearer.

Comment: yes you are right, I modified the code. This is the global variable defination . But i didn't understand the meaning of the same. Can you please clear it?

Answer (score 1):

It means nothing, it is gibberish and will not compile on a C compiler.

Most likely somebody was trying to initialize a struct but failed.

Comment: Or possibly, somebody was trying to copy/paste the actual source code but failed.